# Application Insights project literal value of severityLevel

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a way to project literal value of severityLevel in Application Insights query?

Consider following query:

```
union
customEvents,
dependencies,
exceptions,
performanceCounters,
traces
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, operation_Name, itemType, severityLevel, message = strcat(name, message, outerMessage), customDimensions, ['details']
```

In the output, severityLevel value is numeric, I want the equivalent descriptive value in according with [SeverityLevel Enum definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.severitylevel?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I am able to get the `severityLevel` descriptive value.
- Use the below query snippet

```cs
union
customEvents,
dependencies,
exceptions,
performanceCounters,
traces
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, operation_Name, itemType, severityLevel, message = strcat(name, message, outerMessage), customDimensions, ['details']

| extend severityLevel = case(severityLevel == 0, "Verbose", 
                       severityLevel == 1, "Information",
                       severityLevel == 2, "Warning", 
                       severityLevel == 3, "Error", 
                       severityLevel == 4, "Critical",                      
                       "-")
```

[image]

[image]